# AOS animation on PrestaShop?

Tags: javascript, animation, prestashop

On my PrestaShop i'm trying to config AOS.

I linked like this on head.tpl

At the top :

```
<link href="../themes/theme_devita4/assets/css/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

At the bottom :

```
<script src="../themes/theme_devita4/assets/js/aos.js"></script>
<script>
   AOS.init();
</script>
```

And added `data-aos="fade-up"` in my div.

But it don't work.

Strangely, animations work only when I open navigator inspector before.

Script is here in view source. It is not http-200. I got this error, but probably don't have anything to do with aos;

```
Error in the source links : Error: request failed with status 404 URL of ressource : preprod2.website.fr/themes/core.js Url of source link : core.js.map
```

If I remove aos script, core.js error still here anyway.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: And what does "view-source" show? Is your script even there? And if it is, what does your network tab say? Is it http-200? And if it is, what does your console say? (turn off filtering) any errors, warnings, or even debug notices?

Comment: Script is here in view source. It is not http-200. 
I got this error, but probably don't have anything to do with aos;

Erreur dans les liens source : Error: request failed with status 404
URL de la ressource : https://preprod2.website.fr/themes/core.js
URL du lien source : core.js.map

Comment: Remember: don't put that information in a comment, _put it in your post_. Everyone should be able to see those details.

Comment: nice. Something called "core.js" feels pretty important. Is this for the actual core.js itself, or just the source map

Comment: For the actual core.js I guess. But if I remove the following script, core.js error is still here.

<script>
   AOS.init();
</script>

Comment: then you shoud probably find out why that is, because if something called core.js isn't loading, I'd imagine nothing will work. It doesn't sound like it's because of code you wrote, but more likely because of code you didn't write (or, even, files you forgot to put in the right place)